# Limiting a filter to a 3 character limit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to js and I need to limit my search bar to only display my values after a user has entered 3 characters into the search, I am doing this because there may be allot of values that could possibly return, therefor a 3 char limit should be in effect.

```
const function = () => {
  if (customerDatas) {
    let data = [];

    if (searchBar != "") {
      data = customerDatas.filter(customerData => {
        return customerData.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchBar.toLowerCase());
      });
    }

    return data;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the length of the search string before filtering, `searchBar.length >= 3`

```
const searchFunction = () => {
  if (customerDatas) {
    let data = [];
    if (searchBar != "" && searchBar.length >= 3) {
      data = customerDatas.filter(customerData => {
        return customerData.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchBar.toLowerCase());
      });
    }
    return data;
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe searchBar is a string and therefore you can use `string.length`

```
if (searchBar != "" && searchBar.length >= 3) {
  data = customerDatas.filter(customerData => {
    return customerData.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchBar.toLowerCase());
  });
}
```